# Containerless if binding not working in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, knockout.js

I recently wanted to show a specific property if it is defined, and if it is not defined I want to show a DIV element with some instructions on it.

But i couldn't figure that out; I've tried with `$root` or even the bind property with it but without success.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
function InvestigatorInfo() {
  var self = this;
  self.Name = ko.observable();
  self.Description = ko.observable();
  self.TypeName = ko.observable();
  self.AssemblyName = ko.observable();
  self.ResultType = ko.observable();
  self.EnumTypeName = ko.observable();
  self.Obsolete = ko.observable();
  self.InvestigatorType = ko.observable();

  self.Properties = ko.observable();
  self.Requires = ko.observable();
}
InvestigatorInfo.prototype.fromJS = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.Name(data.Name || "");
  self.Description(data.Description || "");
  self.TypeName(data.TypeName || "");
  self.AssemblyName(data.AssemblyName || "");
  self.ResultType(data.ResultType || "");
  self.EnumTypeName(data.EnumTypeName || "");
  self.Obsolete(data.Obsolete || "");
  self.InvestigatorType(data.InvestigatorType || "");

  self.Properties(data.Properties.Properties || []);
  self.Requires(data.Requires.Interfaces || []);
}
```

And my index:

```
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion" data-bind="foreach:InvestigatorInfos">
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header">
      <i class="material-icons">view_quilt</i>
      <p class="blue-text" data-bind="text: TypeName"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">

      <p class="style_p_row" ><b>AssemblyName:</b> <span data-bind="text: AssemblyName"></span></p>
                  <!-- ko if:Description -->
                  <p class="style_p_row" ><b>Description:</b> <span data-bind="text: Description"></span></p>
                  <!-- /ko -->
                  <!-- ko if:EnumTypeName -->
                  <p class="style_p_row" >
                  <b>EnumTypeName: </b><span data-bind="text: EnumTypeName"></span></p>
                  <!-- /ko -->
                  <p class="style_p_row" >
                  <b>InvestigatorType:</b> <span class="investigatortype-class" data-bind="text:investigatorName[InvestigatorType]"></span></p>
                  <p class="style_p_row" ><b>Name: </b><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></p>
                   <!-- ko if:Obsolete -->
                  <p class="style_p_row" ><b>Obsolete: </b><span data-bind="text: Obsolete"></span></p>
                   <!-- /ko -->
                  <p class="style_p_row" ><b>TypeName: </b><span data-bind="text: TypeName"></span></p>
                  <!-- ko if:ResultType -->
                  <p class="style_p_row" ><b>ResultType: </b><span data-bind="text: resultName[ResultType]"></span></p>
                  <!-- /ko -->

      <!-- ko ifnot:Properties-->
      <p class="blue-text padding_p">Properties</p>
      nothing is set
      <!-- /ko -->
      <!-- ko if: Properties-->
      <table class="bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th data-field="Name">Name</th>
            <th data-field="Converter">Converter</th>
            <th data-field="ValidationName">ValidationName</th>
            <th data-field="EnumTypeName">EnumTypeName</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Properties">
          <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

The `Properties` section within `ko if: Properties` always shows up, even if there are no values in the array behind it, rather than the elements defined within `ko ifnot: Properties`.

JSON data:

```
{
    "BrickInfos":  {
                       "BrickInfos":  [
                                          {
                                              "Properties":  {
                                                                 "Properties":  [

                                                                                ]
                                                             },
                                              "Implements":  {
                                                                 "Interfaces":  [
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        "TypeName":  "ITSR2.Bricks.Access.IAccessBareBoneBrick"
                                                                                    },
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        "TypeName":  "ITSR2.Bricks.Access.IAccessAppBrick"
                                                                                    }
                                                                                ]
                                                             },
                                              "Name":  "AccessBareBoneApp",
                                              "Description":  "",
                                              "TypeName":  "ITSR2.Bricks.Access.AccessBareBoneApp",
                                              "AssemblyName":  "ITSR2.Bricks.MSOffice, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
                                              "Obsolete":  false
                                          },
                                          {
                                              "Properties":  {
                                                                 "Properties":  [
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        "Name":  "MainFile",
                                                                                        "Description":  "",
                                                                                        "ValidationType":  4,
                                                                                        "Converter":  8,
                                                                                        "EnumTypeName":  ""
                                                                                    }
                                                                                ]
                                                             },
                                              "Implements":  {
                                                                 "Interfaces":  [
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        "TypeName":  "ITSR2.Bricks.Access.IAccessBrick"
                                                                                    },
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        "TypeName":  "ITSR2.Bricks.Access.IAccessAppBrick"
                                                                                    }
                                                                                ]
                                                             },
                                              "Name":  "AccessFile",
                                              "Description":  "",
                                              "TypeName":  "ITSR2.Bricks.Access.AccessFile",
                                              "AssemblyName":  "ITSR2.Bricks.MSOffice, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
                                              "Obsolete":  false
                                          },
                                     ]
                    }
}
```

Comment: reduced some code, hope it helps

Comment: Are you talking about the `<!-- ko if: Properties-->` bit?

Comment: yes the if binding is not working

Answer (score 1):

Your `Properties` property is an `observable` which looks like it holds an array, and is either set to `data.Properties.Properties` or an empty array (`[]`).

`[]` is a ["truthy" value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), so even if the code has assigned `[]` to `Properties`, the knockout `if` binding will see it as being populated.  You need to check the length of it:

```
<!-- ko if:Properties().length == 0-->
```

Note the `()` - we need to call the observable to get the underlying array - the observable itself doesn't have a `length` property.

Regarding your update, taking `Obsolete` as another example, you're passing it `false`.  This means that:

```
<!-- ko if: Obsolete -->
```

Is never going to show it's contents, as it's clearly `false`.  You need to tailor it to the values you're expecting - since you're setting the default value to `""`, you could check for that:

```
<!-- ko ifnot: Obsolete() === "" -->
```

So if it's specifically a blank string, it won't display, anything else will be displayed.  Each of your properties will need to have a similar check depending on what you're passing to them and whether any "valid" values that you want to display could end up being treated as falsy values.

Comment: Ok that worked, however i want to use the if binding also for `<!-- ko if:Description -->
                          <p class="style_p_row" ><b>Description:</b> <span data-bind="text: Description"></span></p>
<!-- /ko -->` and this is not an array observable

Comment: @Muli if you want to track the changes on your `Properties` array (added/removed elements) you should declare it as `ko.observableArray()`

Comment: @Muli Are you sure about `Description`?  I ask because `""` is [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and should work ok

Comment: Sry it seems that other propertys are also not showing with the if binding, updated some propertys in the code

Comment: @Muli You'll need to show some example data that you're passing in, because they'll all work (or not) in the same way.  Perhaps the data you're passing in is causing some truthy/falsy issues that you're not expecting.

Comment: @JamesThorpe added the data, Description is always empty, but need to check it always, and ResultType and InvestigatorType are converted than into strings(cuz they hold INT values)

Comment: @Muli So for example you're passing `Obsolete` as `false`.  In that case, are you expecting it to be visible with the text `"false"`?

Comment: i want to check if it has something, and so also for other properties like ResultType etc

Comment: @Muli At this stage I'm going to respectfully suggest that you think about it a bit more yourself - I've covered off arrays and booleans, you should now be able to apply the same concepts to your other properties...

Comment: Thank you for your answer and it really helped, but i still couldn't figure that out with obsolete, im trying `<!-- ko ifnot: Obsolete() ==='' -->`  with on my main.js `self.Obsolete(data.Obsolete || "");` but it still wont show 'false' .